# pandas retaining column after flattening json

Tags: python, pandas, csv, json-normalize

I have a pandas dataframe where each row corresponds to a news article, and each cell in the row contains one dictionary that contains stock ticker information as well as some metrics. The dataframe also contains a time_published column, which contains the publishing date and time corresponding to the row for the article.

I flattened the table into a more workable format, but due to the way I did it, I'm now missing the time_published data in my final table. I'm not quite sure how to make it so that I can keep it.

This is the original table:

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40 | 41 | time_published |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | {'ticker': 'RYCEF', 'relevance_score': '0.079921', 'ticker_sentiment_score': '0.091132', 'ticker_sentiment_label': 'Neutral'} |  |  | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 20240211T042031 |
| 1 |  |  |  | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 20240211T034349 |
| 2 | {'ticker': 'FOREX:IDR', 'relevance_score': '0.047371', 'ticker_sentiment_score': '0.0', 'ticker_sentiment_label': 'Neutral'} | {'ticker': 'FOREX:JPY', 'relevance_score': '0.094576', 'ticker_sentiment_score': '0.079538', 'ticker_sentiment_label': 'Neutral'} |  | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 20240211T033015 |
| 3 |  |  |  | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 20240211T031049 |
| 4 | {'ticker': 'BLK', 'relevance_score': '0.080188', 'ticker_sentiment_score': '-0.036152', 'ticker_sentiment_label': 'Neutral'} | {'ticker': 'GOOG', 'relevance_score': '0.080188', 'ticker_sentiment_score': '0.0', 'ticker_sentiment_label': 'Neutral'} | {'ticker': 'CRYPTO:BTC', 'relevance_score': '0.237358', 'ticker_sentiment_score': '0.229927', 'ticker_sentiment_label': 'Somewhat-Bullish'} | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 20240211T023653 |

I used the following code chunk to flatten the table into a workable format:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame() 
for i in range(0, 41):
    df_flat_ticker_temp = pd.json_normalize(df_flat_ticker[i])
    df_final = pd.concat([df_final, df_flat_ticker_temp])
    df_final = df_final.dropna()
```

Resulting in this table:

| index | ticker | relevance_score | ticker_sentiment_score | ticker_sentiment_label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | RYCEF | 0.079921 | 0.091132 | Neutral |
| 2 | FOREX:IDR | 0.047371 | 0.0 | Neutral |
| 4 | BLK | 0.080188 | -0.036152 | Neutral |
| 5 | NSC | 0.329551 | -0.319278 | Somewhat-Bearish |
| 6 | FOREX:EUR | 0.043499 | -0.222413 | Somewhat-Bearish |
| 7 | FOREX:EUR | 0.259727 | 0.11301 | Neutral |
| 8 | VZ | 0.390613 | 0.331239 | Somewhat-Bullish |
| 9 | BABA | 0.064449 | 0.0 | Neutral |
| 10 | ADM | 0.376704 | 0.166407 | Somewhat-Bullish |
| 11 | EVGGF | 0.098255 | -0.010632 | Neutral |

I am happy with this table, but the only problem is that I cannot find a way to preserve the time_published data due to the way the table was originally formatted. My difficulty with this task arises from the fact that in the original table, an entry in the time_published column corresponds with all of the dictionaries in that row, but in my final table each of those dictionaries is now a separate row. I'd appreciate any help or advice from someone more skilled at pandas than I am on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the `time_published` column back in to each set of columns you append to `df_final`:

```py
for i in range(42):
    df_flat_ticker_temp = pd.json_normalize(df_flat_ticker[i])
    df_final = pd.concat([df_final, pd.concat([df_flat_ticker_temp, df['time_published']], axis=1)])

df_final = df_final.dropna()
```

Output for your sample data:

```
       ticker relevance_score ticker_sentiment_score ticker_sentiment_label   time_published
0       RYCEF        0.079921               0.091132                Neutral  20240211T042031
2   FOREX:IDR        0.047371                    0.0                Neutral  20240211T033015
4         BLK        0.080188              -0.036152                Neutral  20240211T023653
2   FOREX:JPY        0.094576               0.079538                Neutral  20240211T033015
4        GOOG        0.080188                    0.0                Neutral  20240211T023653
4  CRYPTO:BTC        0.237358               0.229927       Somewhat-Bullish  20240211T023653
```

Note that you need `range(42)` to cover all your columns (up to 41).

Also you could use `assign` instead of a nested `concat`:

```py
df_final = pd.concat([df_final, df_flat_ticker_temp.assign(time_published=df['time_published'])])
```